# Document DB SDK with ORDER BY caused ServiceUnvailableException

Tags: database, indexing, azure-cosmosdb, azure-sdk-.net

I'm using DocumentDB. Given index policy:

**messageType**: string - precision -1

**deviceId**: string - precision -1

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c._ts >= 1563721200 AND c._ts < 1563807600 AND c.messageType = 'attack' AND c.deviceId >= 'A' AND c.deviceId < 'Z'
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c._ts >= 1563721200 AND c._ts < 1563807600 AND c.messageType = 'attack' AND c.deviceId >= 'A' AND c.deviceId < 'Z' ORDER BY c._ts DESC
```

Executing code:

```
var query = dbClientSource.CreateDocumentQuery<Document(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(db, collection),
             sql,
             new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 100, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
             .AsDocumentQuery();
while (query.HasMoreResults)
       var result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Telemetry>();
```

Query 1 worked, however query 2 throw exception:

```
{
  "code": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "message": "The request failed because the client was unable to establish connections to 1 endpoints across 1 regions. The client CPU was overloaded during the attempted request.
}
```

The different thing is "ORDER BY" command.
Is there any solutions?

Comment: what is the partitionKey?

Comment: PartitionKey is deviceId. Since the query use "EnableCrossPartitionKey", I think it may not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the query 2 in portal and it works like a charm.
So, in the application I changed ConnectionPolicy to:

*Gateway - Https*

Now the application is working.
This issue look like relates to Document DB SDK, to make sure I will continue to test and report to Github repository.

Comment: This case happen due to network retriction, Direct-TCP cannot work. However, it is very strange to make CPU 100% and throw ServiceUnAvailableException.